# Need to include JavaScript, ERB partial, and a render method from a helper in my own gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb, rails-engines, railtie

From what I've been able to research online a Rails::Engine would allow me to mimic the Rails paths.  I figured this would allow me to include everything just by placing them in the equivalent directories.  As I have found the directories aren't loading the assets or helpers.  I have not mounted the Rails Engine nor isolated it as I want everything to be included locally.  It won't interfere with the namespace.

I would prefer a Railtie, but I am unaware of howto add a JavaScript file to the asset pipeline, and a partial to the view.  But I can get a helper method working with a Railtie.

So the question is basically howto include JavaScript, and ERB partial, and a helper via a gem.  Not curious at all about gem building, I know that.  And I'm not concerned about rendering a partial from a helper method.  Just need to know how to include the appropriate assets/partials so that they load with whatever Rails application which requires the gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since completed a project with all that I've described here.  Feel free to use the source as a template for completing your own projects.

[Dynaspan - An AJAX in place text to input Rails gem](https://github.com/danielpclark/dynaspan)